# Is this hard floor mat in our closet made from asbestos?

Tags: asbestos

The house was built in 1930 and this mat is in an unfinished closet, it's about 2 1/2' x 6'. It's not glued down and I could literally pick it up and take it out of the house if I wanted. But it is cracking and I just didn't want to touch it. Is this asbestos and since it could be picked right up do I really need an asbestos professional to pick it up and remove it?

Here is a couple pictures of it.

[image]
[image]

Comment: asbestos != plutonium; just remove it if you're concerned, it's not a treasure anyway. a small dust mask or just holding your breath should suffice, unless you ask someone who makes a living from remediation. I'm not saying it's 100% benign, but it's certainly not a deadly toxin; it's a long term exposure concern, like cleaning products and insecticides or even cigarettes; one sniff won't give you lung cancer...

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to tell, but it’s the right age. The EPA regulates the testing, abatement, and disposal of asbestos. The one thing I’ve learned over the years is that it needs to be friable to be harmful. This is not friable and you can easily remove it if you like.

However, I’d be careful not to break it up and I’d wet it down before I tried to move it. That is to say, I’d spray it with water and wrap it in a large sheet in case it did break up.

Also, you can buy test kits to determine if it is asbestos from your local hardware store. If it is asbestos, call your local sanitation department and dispose of it properly.